# How to exclude transitive dependency

Tags: java, cxf, gradle, jakarta-mail

I use `JavaMail` in the same project with cxf. cxf brings an older version of `JavaMail` which does not suit me. How to excluded?
I did so:

> ```
> compile (group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-bindings-soap', version: apacheCfxVersion)  {
>    exclude module: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec'
> }
> ```

But it did not help. I find in the war WEB-INF \ lib \ geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec'
}
```