# How to exclude JUnit as transitive dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit, dependencies

I have noticed that I have an unwanted transitive dependency on `junit:junit-dep:4.11` in my build.gradle file:

```
+--- com.myprojectabc-cmis:0.3.1
|    \--- org.alfresco.cmis.client:alfresco-opencmis-extension:1.1
|         \--- junit:junit-dep:4.11
|              \--- junit:junit:4.11
|                   \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

This JUnit dependency is a potential source of conflict, since  I normally use the version 4.12 in my project. Also, I don't want a JUnit dependency within my business logic. So it needs to be `excluded`. As a gradle newbie I'm having difficulties to find a solution. I've read the docs and also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641546/exclude-junit-from-eclipse-exported-jar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971023/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency) and still couldn't figure out the right way to do it. I've also tried this:

```
compile('com.myprojectabc-cmis:0.3.1') {
 exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit:4.11' 
}
```

and this:

```
compile('com.myprojectabc-cmis:0.3.1') {
   exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit-dep:4.11' 
}
```

Gradle loads without problems when I make this change. But in the dependency tree I still see the dependency. So obviously it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html, https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991, and so on.

Comment: I've already read this, mate. didnt help. Thx tho.

Comment: Please show the relevant portions of your Gradle file. It’s unlikely (but not impossible) there’s a runtime junit dependency, but would to see how, explicitly, you’re doing the exclude. If you’re creating an artifact you can also check within that artifact.

Comment: ok I edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, answer was easier than I thought:

```
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit-dep'
```